# Pass Multiple values while searching a json

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to search multiple values index from a column name. Say I need to search for 3 values: 10,somestr1 and somestr2,
I have tried using json search command in mysql but it returns only a single index. I need to get multiple indexes. Please don't suggest like command as '%10%'. This part can be unique and will not follow any pattern

```
SELECT JSON_SEARCH(columnname, 'all', '10', NULL, '$.data.somepath');
```